# jsf rendered not evaluated?

Tags: jsf, el, myfaces

I want the checkbox only to be rendered, if the label is not empty.

```
<tr:panelCaptionGroup>
...
    <tr:selectBooleanCheckbox 
        id="XField1"
        render="#{!empty myController.form.model.XField1}"
        value="#{myController.form.model.XFieldChecked1}"
        text="#{myController.form.model.XField1}"
        simple="false" />
</tr:panelCaptionGroup>
```

XField1 is a String, XFieldChecked1 is a Boolean. It does not work, it always shows the checkbox, even if the string is null or "".

In that case, the output is (removed some attributes for clarity):

```
<table border="0" summary="" class="af_selectBooleanCheckbox" id="modelXField3__xc_">  
<tbody><tr>
  <td nowrap="" class="af_selectBooleanCheckbox_label"></td>
  <td valign="top" nowrap="" class="AFContentCell">
    <span id="modelXField3__xc_c" class="af_selectBooleanCheckbox_content">
      <input type="checkbox" value="t" name="modelXField3" id="modelXField3">
      <label for="modelXField3"></label>
    </span>
  </td>
</tr></tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for every other JSF [UI component](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html), the attribute name is `rendered`, not `render`.

#### See also:

- [`<tr:selectBooleanCheckbox>` tag documentation](http://myfaces.apache.org/trinidad/trinidad-api/tagdoc/tr_selectBooleanCheckbox.html)